# Неправильное отображение метки unity2d

Tags: дефект, метки, синонимы-меток

Когда пытаюсь поставить метку unity2d -- она автоматически меняется на unity3d, хотя в списке вариант unity2d есть.

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, сценарий подробнее так же как и используемый браузер. Я не смог воспроизвести, unity2d - поставил как тег без проблем.

Comment: @AntonMenshov а у вас должны были быть проблемы, потому что unity2d является синонимом unity3d

Comment: @AntonMenshov Исполбзую Google Chrome. 1. Нажимаю добавить метку 2. Пишу unity2d 3. Подтвераждаю 4. Метка превращается в unity3d

Comment: Упс. во время редактирования вопроса такого эффекта нет - а дальше я не стал пробовать. Ошибся.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метки [unity2d](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity2d) и [unity3d](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) объявлены синонимами. Это видно на [странице синонимов метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/unity3d/synonyms). Т.о. любое использование синонимов при публикации/редактировании вопроса приводит к замене на основную метку. С точки зрения логики работы меток дефекта тут нет. А вот судить о том, должны ли эти метки действительно быть синонимами, я не берусь. Однако, на enSO они тоже являются [синонимами](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unity3d/synonyms).